# Bug in submit credit card event form when processor returns error

Tags: civievent, payment-processor

There is a problem with one of the paths to register a contact for an event where if an error is returned from the payment processor (in this case IATS) the form just hangs and never returns. When the page it reloaded it displays the error.
[image]

If you go to the events tab of a contact and click Submit Credit Card Registration, the form only works correctly if the payment processor response is positive.
[image]

This only happens when the form is an overlay/popup. 
[image]
If the user opens the link in a new tab instead of allowing for the overlay, the error is returned to the user (although in a less than pretty way). 
[image]
[image]
This does not happen in the same context for contributions, that form reacts well to all situations. 
The form does not hang if the response from the processor does not contain an error message.

I'm submitting this here to get feedback before submitting this to gitlab as an issue

Comment: i couldn't actually see where the $ amount was on any of those screens (Blame ageing eyes perhaps). Just checking this isn't an issue (which bit us recently with a different payment gate) of problems with $0 amounts

Comment: I posted just enough to give an idea of the workflows that works and that does not. The $ amount and all other expected fields show in both cases. 
IATS has a test account available to anyone, if you set up a payment processor as documented here you should be able to replicate the issue,  https://home.iatspayments.com/developer-info/testing-cards/#3049

(set this data for the live payment data for a testing payment processor)

Comment: Hey ericG - I find "Error bubbles" come in late on a number of pages. I've gotten in the habit of opening a new window - copy the url to see the bubble (if things hang/take long).

Comment: Hey petednz - iATS minimum charge is $1 - it's on my ToDo list somewhere to report that back to the admin before attempting to transact with iATS Payments - but it has not surfaced near the top yet.

Comment: KarinG, since this works totally correctly in a similar context (start from contact record, go to contributions tab, make credit card contribution in overlay) even when errors are returned, but not in Event reg, I was hoping that someone more familiar with how these forms work in overlay mode would be able to find the problem without too much effort. While we've instructed users in how to avoid the problem, the inconsistency seems to indicate this can be resolved (however it's done in events)